# How do we check whether a dynamic clay object has a property?

Tags: c#, dynamic, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, clay

I have a dynamic object, *that I think is implemented with Clay*. It has one of two possible property names. I want to use which ever property name is available. The following doesn't work:

```
dynamic workItemPart = item.WorkItem; // is an Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart
var learnMore = workItemPart.LearnMore ?? workItemPart.LearnMoreField;
```

It throws a `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException`:

> does not contain a definition for 'LearnMore'

**How do we check if a dynamic Clay object has a property?** [In JavaScript, for instance, we can do the following.](http://repl.it/WUJ)

```
var workItemPart = {
    LearnMoreField: "Sure"    
    }
console.log(workItemPart.LearnMore || workItemPart.LearnMoreField);
```

Is there anything this concise in C# with Clay?

Related:

[Is Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart implemented with Clay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166799/is-orchard-contentmanagement-contentpart-implemented-with-clay)

https://twitter.com/bleroy/status/497078654405312512

Comment: Reflection should work, right?

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: if workItemPart is dynamic it shouldn't give you a compiler error. I don't really understand what do you mean by dynamic here

Comment: @Selman22 That actually wasn't the answer. Thank you, though, as I had assigned it to a `var` not a `dynamic`.

Comment: but be aware that if it hasn't the property `LearnMore` it will throw `RuntimeBinderException` at runtime. if the property does exists but is null then it won't be a problem

Comment: It hasn't the property. That is what I want to determine. That is the whole question. How do we test whether the object has the property?

Comment: @MatthewHagemann Meh. Is there no other way?

Comment: Can you cast `Clay` to `IDictionary` and use `ContainsKey("LearnMore")`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the indexed approach:

```
var learnMore = workItemPart["LearnMore"] != null ? 
     workItemPart.LearnMore : workItemPart.LearnMoreField;
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure why it doesn't. Both methods should work.

```
        dynamic New = new ClayFactory();
        var person = New.Person();
        person.skill = "Outstanding";
        var talent = person.talent;
        var talentTwo = person["talent"];
        var skill = person.talent ?? person.skill;
        Console.WriteLine(skill);
        skill = person.skill ?? person.talent;
        Console.WriteLine(skill);
```

Perhaps it is Orchard throwing you a curveball ...

Interesting enough, the null-coalesce operator does not process the first test case correctly. However, the standard test succeeds:

```
        skill = person.talent != null ? person.talent : person.skill;
        Console.WriteLine(skill);
```

Not sure what to advise you at this point.

Comment: That works. I wish there were a more concise way. In JavaScript, for instance, we can be incredibly concise and do the same thing.

Comment: how does this work ? `dynamic obj = new {Name = "Foo"}; var name = obj["Name"];` throws exception for me. Am I missing something ?

Comment: This throws an exception too: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart'`

Comment: Maybe Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart isn't implement with Clay after all.

Comment: Here is the thing ... I hear war drums already, to go after the Clay creator ... :) If you want loosely typed, use agnostic language, by all means, code in JavaScript. Just glancing over `New.Person()` makes me sick that I even wrote this piece of code to test your particular problem. That's not what C# has been created for. Having said that, if you need an approach which will dynamically create new  types with all kinds of functions, there is always T4 templates and dynamic runtime compilation. You can perform all kinds of magic tricks using them.

Comment: Orchard doesn't use Clay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension method to check if property exists:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool HasProperty(this object d, string propertyName)
    {
        return d.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bool hasProperty = Extensions.HasProperty(workItemPart, "LearnMore");

var learnMore =  hasProperty ? workItemPart.LearnMore : workItemPart.LearnMoreField;
```

It doesn't look like an extension method though.. since the `workItemPart` is dynamic you need to call it explicitly by specifying the class name.

Comment: This works too, though it is pretty verbose compared to what JavaScript gives us. Its good parts are so good.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work either. GetProperty is returning null.

Answer (score 1):

@Shaun Luttin, quite an old issue in the context of the Orchard cms, but recently I've proposed this [pull request](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/5542/files) that has been committed

So, now you can use the following without throwing an exception

```
    if (contentItem.SomePart != null)
    if (part.SomeField != null)
```

The ContentItem and ContentPart classes inherit from System.Dynamic.DynamicObject and override the TryGetMember() method. And, before, if no property found the method returned false

```
    return false;
```

Now, even if the result object (the out parameter of the method) is set to null, the method return true which prevents from throwing an exception

```
    result = null;
    return true;
```

For more details, see the related PR link above

Best