# Is Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart implemented with Clay?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, clay

I previously asked [How do we check whether a dynamic clay object has a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149535/how-do-we-check-whether-a-dynamic-clay-object-has-a-property) My question assumed that an `Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart` was a dynamic Clay object. Is it a dynamic Clay object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It used to be the case, but it was recently removed, and replaced with several more specialized, and faster implementations of dynamic. The Clay dependency is completely gone.